# Get pandoc to generate PDF with sans-serif font family

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I'm trying to use pandoc to generate a PDF from Markdown source. I'd like the output to use only sans-serif fonts. Input:

```
# Hello

This is a test.
```

Command line:

```
pandoc -o output.pdf input.md --variable=fontfamily:arev
```

I get a fine-looking PDF, but the text is serif. Output:

[image: Screenshot of PDF generated from Markdown source with pandoc showing serif fonts]

I tried many different command lines, but the font (family) never changes.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed pandoc via apt-get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to install arev, bera and mathdesign fonts first, but your command worked fine for me:

[image: screenshot]

For Ubuntu and TeXLive these fonts are located in the package [`texlive-fonts-extra`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/texlive-fonts-extra)

The version from the Ubuntu repositories is quite old, so better first go [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases) and install the latest from the Debian package.

Comment: I installed `texlive-fonts-extra` but I get the same result (output uses serif fonts). Maybe there's another package I need to install?

Comment: I don't know, is there any warning in the log file that could help? By the way, which version of pandoc are you using? the one in the repositories is usually quite old.

Comment: Ooh, good call on the version! I was using 1.12.2.1. Must just be what Ubuntu 14.04 ships with. I grabbed a 1.17.0.2 deb package off https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases and now the output PDF has sans-serif fonts as expected. Would you like to add that to your answer, and I'll accept it?