# Pandoc: Change font family to sans while converting from Markdown to HTML

Tags: html, command-line, markdown, pandoc, font-family

I successfully get a nice formatted text I could paste anywhere using:

```
cat myFile.md | pandoc -s -f markdown -t html | xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html
```

[`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip) is a command line interface to X selections (clipboard). With `... -t html -o myFile.html` works fine too.

I'm trying to change the font family, from the default Serif to some other Sans-serif font family. I found a lot of examples with LaTex, PDF and DOC, but no one that works in this scenario. Tried a lot of fonts (listed from `fc-list : family`, even after installing `texlive-xetex` package). The Closest answer I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37232597/4970442).

I'm trying to just use certain parameters on CLI, trying to avoid things like `--css source/styles.css`.

Using pandoc 1.19.2.4 over Ubuntu 18.04.

Some `--variable` I tried:

```sh
-V fontfamily:arev
-V fontfamily:Ubuntu
-V fontfamilyoptions:sfdefault
-V "mainfont:DejaVuSans"
-V mainfont="DejaVu Sans Serif"
-V "sansfont:DejaVuSans"
```

**Edit 1**:

Based on [mb21's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298129/4970442), since Pandoc 1.12.x ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/188590)) is possible to provide more metadata to Pandoc adding [a YAML block code](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block).

On newer Pandoc versions, I also added a title key to avoid the "[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty  element.".

```
---
title: My File
header-includes: |
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Liberation Sans";
    }
  </style>
---
```

I still don't see the fundamental difference in this aspect between coming from Markdown instead of LaTeX, and going to HTML instead of PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: This is possible in pandoc 2.11. For details, see the [MANUAL](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-html), but for example:

```
---
mainfont: sans-serif
---

my markdown
```

If your font name includes spaces then specify name in quotes escaped with backslash:

```
---
mainfont: \"Sanskrit 2020\"
---
```

---

**Old answer**: The font variables you mention are only for LaTeX/PDF output. To style HTML, you need CSS. You can for example put this in your markdown file:

```
---
header-includes: |
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
---

my markdown
```

Alternatively you can:

- use `--css`
- copy the [default `styles.html`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/templates/styles.html) [partial](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#partials) in `~/.pandoc/templates/styles.html` and modify it. (You can just create the directories if they doen't exist.)
- use a [template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) like [this one](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/6601/files)...

Also: pandoc 1.19 is ancient, see https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Answer (score 2):

Another solution based on [mb21's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298129/4970442) is using a separated YAML file,  `--metadata-file` option with that code in for e.g. `metadata.yaml`.

I provide the title with `--metadata`.

```
cat myFile.md | pandoc -s -f markdown -t html --metadata-file metadata.yaml --metadata title="My File" -o myFile.html
```

A `metadata.yaml` content example:

```yaml
---
header-includes: |
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
    }
  </style>
---
```

AFAIK is not possible to provide the whole styling just through `--metadata` on the same on-liner command.

Another very useful onliner to convert clipboard to formatted rendered text is (on Mac use `pbpaste`):

```
xsel -b | pandoc -s -f markdown -t html | xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html
```