# Custom font to table using kableExtra

Tags: r, fonts, kable, kableextra

my company requires all outputs to have the font "Neue Haas Grotesk", how would I format my table in R to use this font? Preferably using kableExtra

Comment: Plenty of options given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293929/pandoc-change-font-family-to-sans-while-converting-from-markdown-to-html).  [Possible duplicate?]

Comment: @Limey I don't see how those options relate to using KableExtra in R, as they mostly reference pandoc and the CLI

Comment: knitr (and kableExtra) are an interface between R(Markdown) and pandoc.